# Find the sign of $\int_{k}^{k+2}\frac{(\sin {\pi x})^c}{x} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Let $$I(k)=\int_{k}^{k+2}\frac{(\sin {\pi x})^c}{x} dx,$$ where $c>0$ is an odd integer, prove that $I(2n)>0,I(2n+1)<0,\forall n\in\mathbb N.$

I can prove this for $c=1,$ 
$$I(k)=\int_{k}^{k+2}\frac{\sin {\pi x}}{x} dx \\
=\int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{\sin {\pi x}}{x} dx+\int_{k+1}^{k+2}\frac{\sin {\pi x}}{x} dx \\ 
=\int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{\sin {\pi x}}{x} dx+\int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{\sin {\pi (x+1)}}{x+1} dx \\
=\int_{k}^{k+1}(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x+1}) \sin {\pi x} dx
=\int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{\sin {\pi x}}{x(x+1)} dx,$$ 
this implies what we want. But I wonder how to prove this for $c>1?$

Comment: I haven't taken a close look at this yet. Would it help to use the pythagorean identity? 

\begin{align}\sin^3(x)&=\sin^2(x)\sin(x)\\&=(1-\cos^2(x))\sin(x)\end{align}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have, since $\sin \pi x > 0$ for $2n < x < 2n+1$, and $\sin \pi x < 0$ for $2n+1 < x < 2(n+1)$, that $\sin \pi x = \lvert\sin \pi x\rvert$ on $[2n,2n+1]$ and $\sin \pi x = -\lvert\sin\pi x\rvert$ on $[2n+1,2n+2]$, hence

$$\begin{align}
I(2n) &= \int_{2n}^{2n+1} \frac{\lvert \sin \pi x\rvert^c}{x}\, dx - \int_{2n+1}^{2(n+1)} \frac{\lvert \sin \pi x\rvert^c}{x}\,dx\\
&= \int_0^1 \lvert \sin \pi x\rvert^c \left(\frac{1}{2n+x} - \frac{1}{2n+1+x}\right)\,dx\\
&> 0.
\end{align}$$

The case for $I(2n+1)$ is analogous, the point is that $\lvert \sin \pi x\rvert^c$ has period $1$, and $\frac1x$ is strictly decreasing, and the sign of $\sin \pi x$ changes at the integers.

Comment: Can you give a little more detais? I don't see how the two "=" come out.

Comment: I've added a few explanations. If that's not enough, ping me.